Prove that a non-negative mixing matrix removing its first row and column, its spectral radius strictly decrease.
The non-negative matrix A is mixing means there exists an m, such that every entries of A^m is positive.
If the matrix after removing is still mixing, the problem will be solved by Perron-Frobenius theorem. If not, I don't how to solve it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/924257

you can take $A$ to have spectral radius of $1$ and it is similar to an irreducible markov matrix via a positive diagonal matrix, then apply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888565/markov-chain-transition-matrix-eigenvalues-textbook-exercise/ .  I suggest "proof 2" where you don't need to consider the (ir)reducibility of the dominated matrix.
